# Is there any way to know when a crontab was installed?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cron

Is there any way to know when a crontab was installed on ubuntu server?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on  [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a default installation of a cron job using `crontab -e`, the cron get logged in `var/log/syslog` file.

You can see when a cron job was was installed from that file by running:

```
grep "END EDIT" /var/log/syslog
```

The date and time is firt on the line.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/56811/147044

Answer (score 2):

You can list user's cron tabs:

```
sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

To see when those files were last changed.

Also, you could read your logs (`/var/log/syslog`) and search for `crontab` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

try crontab -e . Add 0 0/5 * * * /your/path/to/script/

Comment: I'm not really sure what question you're trying to answer here. `0/5` isn't even valid cron syntax.